# Rearrange regression equation that includes a dummy variable

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, linear-model, linear-algebra

This is my regression equation:

$10 = 5.44 + 0.26X_1 - 3.19X_2$

$X_2$ is a dummy predictor with two levels. Assume that the value of $X_2$ is 1 therefore regression equation is:

$10 = 5.44 + 0.26X_1 - 3.19$

How can I rearrange the equation to find $X_1$? This isn't homework, it's my own data collected as a hobby.

Comment: Are you solving for $X1_i$ for a given point $Y_i$ and $X2_i$?

Comment: How come the "dependent variable" is a fixed number, $10$?

Comment: Dependent variable isn't fixed, it's just the value of $Y$ for which I want to know the value of $X_1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with an equation is that at each step you do things that preserve the equality*

* (loosely expressed as "do the same thing to both sides" - which is accurate if you don't do things that remove solutions nor add solutions that don't solve the original). For example, you can add some number to both sides.

$ 5.44 + 0.26X_1 - 3.19=10$

... now  add or subtract the same numbers on both sides to isolate $X_1$:

$ 5.44 - 5.44 + 0.26X_1 - 3.19=10-5.44$  gives

$0.26X_1 - 3.19=10-5.44$

$0.26X_1 - 3.19+3.19=10-5.44+3.19$

$0.26X_1=10-5.44+3.19$ ... now divide both sides by the same (non-zero) quantity

$0.26X_1/0.26=(10-5.44+3.19)/0.26$

$X_1=(10-5.44+3.19)/0.26 = 29.80769$

You can do similar manipulations when $X_2$ takes a different value. Or you can keep $X_2$ just as $X_2$ until after it has been rearranged to make $X_1$ the subject.